# Is there a way to get the specific email address from a Gmail message object in Google app scripts?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

In Google App Scripts to process a list of email messages in my inbox.
From the messages I need to get the from and to addresses of each message.
When I use the
message.getFrom() method to get the from address it returns something like this: "FirstName LastName ". But, what I want is the plain email address: "email@domain.com" I can't find a method on the GmailApp object, or the Message object, that would return just this information.

getFrom() returns a simple string, not an address object that can be dissected further.
Am I missing something?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`getFrom()` method should return the sender of the message in the format `Some Person <someone@somewhere.com>`. If you need just the email address portion of the string, you can extract it using regular expression like this (adapted example from [getFrom() method description](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message#getFrom())):

```
var thread = GmailApp.getInboxThreads(0,1)[0]; // get first thread in inbox
var message = thread.getMessages()[0]; // get first message
Logger.log(message.getFrom().replace(/^.+<([^>]+)>$/, "$1"));
```

That regex replace the string returned by getFrom() method with the part of the string in angle brackets (the sender's email address).

Answer (score 2):

After you get the GmailMessage object, you can get the email address by first getting the RFC Header named "From" using `GmailMessage.getHeader("From")`, and then apply a certain Regular Expression to it.

Like this:

```
 // Get email from RFC Header "From"
 var rfcHeaderFrom = message.getHeader("From");
 var rfcHeaderFromMailRegex = /[^< ]+(?=>)/g;

 var mailSender = rfcHeaderFrom.match(rfcHeaderFromMailRegex)[0];
```

That will return an email address like: `"user@example.com"`