# How to retrieve email addresses from gmail addon

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-addons

I'm new to Gmail add-ons. Could you please help me how to retrieve current email from address, to address and cc addresses?

```
GmailApp.getMessageById(messageId).getTo()
GmailApp.getMessageById(messageId).getFrom() is displaying names but not giving email addresses.
```

Comment: Use `Session` class

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  But as per the document https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session this is giving the user information who is running the script.  But for me I need to know the from address  and to addresses of the mail information.

Comment: Can't reproduce. I get name as well as the e-mail address in logs.

Comment: I am getting current logged in user details not getting a way to retrieve to addresses

Comment: check [How to get email address from GmailMessage object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26242591/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-specific-email-address-from-a-gmail-message-object-in/59248442#59248442)

Answer (score 4):

After getting the messageId, you can run the code below to get the GmailMessage.

```
var message = GmailApp.getMessageById(messageId);
```

This returns GmailMessage object. Now you can use methods such as getTo(), getFrom(), getCC(), getBcc(). Read more about GmailMessage [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message). You can use it like,

```
var from = message.getFrom();
```

It gives name and email address of the sender. To get email address only, use regular expressions.

```
var senderEmail = from.replace(/^.+<([^>]+)>$/, "$1");
```

Comment: wow, it works. but it seems like an "hack" to me... is this documented somewhere?